# Devise login proceeds without checking reCaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, recaptcha

I have a ruby project with devise sign in. There is the log in form:

```
= simple_form_for(Company.new, url: new_company_session_url(I18n.locale)) do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: false
        = f.input :password, required: false
        - unless Rails.env.development?
          .row
            .col-md-12{style: "float: left;"}
              = recaptcha_tags
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, t('devise.session.button'),  class: 'btn btn-lg btn-block'
```

And my session create controller:

```
if verify_recaptcha or Rails.env.development?
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."
      flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
      render :new
    end
```

So, when i try to log in without checking recaptcha, it goes in to else and redirect me back to the log in form again. But if i refresh the page, i see the session already created. How is it still able to create the session?

trace log:

```
Processing by Company::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "company"=>{"email"=>"email", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "g-recaptcha-response"=>"", "commit"=>"Sign in", "locale"=>"en"}
Rendering layout layouts/application.haml
Rendering company/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application
Rendered company/sessions/_form.html.haml (Duration: 4.5ms | Allocations: 1974)
Rendered company/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 9.7ms | Allocations: 4707)
Rendered layouts/partials/_head.haml (Duration: 1.3ms | Allocations: 422)
Rendered layouts/partials/_messages.haml (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 29)
Company Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "email"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  BEGIN
Company Update (1.2ms)  UPDATE "companies" SET "sign_in_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_at" = $3, "last_sign_in_ip" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "companies"."id" = $6  [["sign_in_count", 715], ["current_sign_in_at", "2023-12-29 09:05:46.712411"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2023-12-29 08:40:18.200032"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "85.153.239.197/32"], ["updated_at", "2023-12-29 09:05:46.713166"], ["id", 11539]]
```

Comment: I changed `render :new` with `redirect_back fallback_location: root_path`, and problem solved. it redirects me back without login. But how is it signs in after `render :new`? I couldn't figure out which code is running after the render.